# Validation failed for: pear mail package

Tags: php, email, pear

```
<?php

    require_once "Mail.php";

    $from = '<from.gmail.com>';
    $to = '<to.yahoo.com>';
    $subject = 'Hi!';
    $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

    $headers = array(
        'From' => $from,
        'To' => $to,
        'Subject' => $subject
    );

    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
            'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
            'port' => '465',
            'auth' => true,
            'username' => 'johndoe@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'passwordxxx'
        ));

    $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

    if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
        echo('<p>' . $mail->getMessage() . '</p>');
    } else {
        echo('<p>Message successfully sent!</p>');
    }

?>
```

However, the program fails at `$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);` with:

> validation failed: johndoe@gmail.com

I've verified that email and password are correct.  If I supply an invalid password, the error changes to

> incorrect password

I've also tried disabling 2-step authentication on my account, but that has not helped. Please advise why I may be getting this validation error when credentials otherwise seem correct?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: All I see is code. Are you sure you have the dependencies setup properly?

Comment: i am using this i got error "validation failed :example@gmail.com"

Comment: i set it properly .using my own mail address but it did't work

Comment: Just to check, is your account setup for two-factor authentication? Not sure if `ssl://smtp.gmail.com` enforces such, but figure it's worth a comment to rule out up front.

Comment: $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
 this line i got error

Comment: suppose i give wrong password it returns "incorrect password" but i give the correct password it returns "validation failed :"

Comment: i disabled 2 step authentication but i didn't work

Answer (score 2):

Usually you get "Validation failed for" when you use invalid characters as email alias in your or recipient's email.

For example:

```
my_email@gmail.com <first_name.last_name>
my_email@gmail.com <first_name@last_name>
```

Invalid characters are:

```
. (dots)
@ (at)
" (double quotes)
[ (bracket opened without closing)
] (bracket closed without opening)
( (parenthesis opened without closing)
) (parenthesis closed without opening)
```

Answer (score 1):

I received the same error.

After experimenting with the fields this worked for me:

Instead of

```
$from = "Sender <sender@example.com>";
```

Try

```
$from = "sender@example.com";
```

So you have just the from email address in the from field. Nothing else. No brackets.

Not a very elegant solution, I admit, but a solution nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

I had got this error when I tried to set `mailFrom` with space and without email:

```
$this->mailFrom = "Lorem ipsum";'
```

Just change it with email address:

```
$this->mailFrom = "Lorem ipsum <no-reply@test.com>";
```

Answer (score -1):

Even if it is a late answer I will post this for others.
"validation failed: " is for receiver addresses not for your credentials.
The issue is that the recipient address has a wrong format that Gmail does not accept.

```
//instead of 
$to = '<to.yahoo.com>';
//use
$to = 'Recipient Name <myname@example.com>'
//or simple 
$to = 'myname@example.com';
```